# Disable index temporarily in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have **1 table** with more than **10 millions records** of employee salary.

I have created few `indexes` and testing on **performance improvement** based on that, But i am facing issue with *disabling the index*, as it says access to the table will not be available in case of disabling the index.

So is there any way to disable the index and then check on trial error for the performance, in order to identify that improvement is due to index or not.

*Drop and re-create* is a tedious process, and i want some alternative on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can help

```
ALTER INDEX indexName ON   tableName 
DISABLE;
```

Comment: Through this process,system is getting hang and not able to complete this transaction.

Comment: Is anyone having quick solution on this, as waiting for 5-7 min to disable the index is not so good idea.

Comment: user8205502 : Do you have any other alternative, without choking up the functionality of sql server ?